# Symfony2 how to redirect to an action without hardcoding route name?

Tags: symfony

I've an **abstract** `CRUDController` extending `Controller`. In my `newAction`, os success, i'd like to redirect to `showAction($slug)` using `redirect` method:

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl($route, $params));
```

But `newAction` is **actually called in the subclass** `UserController`, so i can't specify route name `$route` in my `CRUDController`.

```
class UserController extends CRUDController { }

abstract class CRUDController extends Controller
{
    /** @Template */
    public function showAction($slug) { }

    /** @Template */
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {

        $model = $this->createModel();
        $form  = $this->createForm($this->createType(), $model);

        if('GET' == $request->getMethod())
            return array('form' => $form->createView());

        $form->bindRequest($request);

        if(!$form->isValid()) return array(
            'errors' => $this->get('validator')->validate($model),
            'form'   => $form->createView()
        );

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $em->persist($model);
        $em->flush();

        // Success, redirect to showAction($slug)
    }

}
```

An example of routes:

```
users_show:
  pattern: /users/show/{slug}
  defaults: { _controller: AcmeSecurityBundle:User:show }
  requirements:
    _method:  GET

users_new:
  pattern: /users/new
  defaults: { _controller: AcmeSecurityBundle:User:new }
  requirements:
    _method:  GET

users_create:
  pattern: /users/new
  defaults: { _controller: AcmeSecurityBundle:User:new }
  requirements:
    _method:  POST
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can work with the whole concept of OO and have an interface method called `getRouteName()` in your **abstract** class:

```
abstract public function getRoute();
```

And then, on your concrete class, or subclass, UserController, you just override and implement that:

```
public function getRoute()
{
    return 'whatever:Route:YouWant';
}
```

So when, on your **abstract** class, call the actual interface method, the OO will handle everything like magic:

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    ...
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl($this->getRouteName(), $params));
}
```

Maybe try that and let us know if does the job right.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, even if it's quite obvious. If you look at the code you see that i'm doing the the same with methods like `createModel()` and `createType()` (they are abstract). But with route... changing it will force you to change also `getRoute`, so i discarded that idea. Thanks anyway.

Comment: i think you have to RETURN -> "return $this->redirect();"

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes create pseudo-interface when I need to do actions like this in sf:

```
interface specialRedirect
{
    public function specialRedirect($slug);
}
```

So then you could do something like this in your abstract class:

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    // ...
    $this->specialRedirect('user', $slug);
}

public function specialRedirect($slug)
{
    // If you don't want to do anything special, just act like normal
    // Success, redirect to showAction($slug)
}
```

But then in `UserController` you extend/implement the interface to your liking:

```
public function specialRedirect($slug)
{
    //here is where you can specify your route name.
    $route = 'Foo_Bar';
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl($route, $params));

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but as a replied to drgomesp this is not DRY. Plus, routes are hardcoded in a method name...

Comment: @Gremo I read your other question -- why not have your abstract controller ask the service it's dealing with for information on how to handle the response?

Comment: can your explain better your question? I'm not sure i can understand it - thanks.