# Redirect using @Route annotations

Tags: symfony

Is there a way to redirect using annotations?

```
/**
 * Delete user
 *
 *
 * @Route("/deleteUser/{user_id}", name="delete_user_from_id")
 * @Template()
 */
public function deleteUserAction($user_id)
{
 //....
 return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('acme_demo_homepage'));
}
```

Can we use annotations instead to avoid this extra line? Something like @redirect?

Comment: AFAIK not possible, i asked a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9719686/symfony2-how-to-redirect-to-an-action-without-hardcoding-route-name

Comment: How would this happen? You would need a complex syntax to answer the question when to redirect, as you cannot annotate within a method. I also doubt it would improve readability. At least the redirect has to happen at a certain point in the code, so code is the way to go. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you guys post an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks :-)

Comment: Annotations are cool, i get it. But please don't use them in every case you think your code looks ugly... We are on the road to the c preprocessor here - even without the performance benefit - the exact reasons modern languages ditched this feature in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it is not possible.

Have a look into FrameworkExtraBundle. A redirect must be triggered in a controller (often after some logic ;) )