# Symfony2 reusable functions in controllers

Tags: php, symfony, controller, reusability

After some time without knowing how to do this properly, and avoid duplicating code in several controllers, I searched and again to seek, but can not find a clear answer.

One case in particular, need to calculate several statistics data completed of an entity. This calculation will use in 3 different controllers.
In two of them, I'll show broken down into different layouts, and on the third, I will use this data to make a global calculation.
business logic for each calculation, involves more than 100 lines of code, I would have to triple in the different controllers.

A scheme could be:

- Calculation fields completed "Data A"
- Calculation fields completed "Data B"
- Calculation fields completed "Data C"

With these 3 values, I make a later total calculation.

The options that I could find are:

- Define a controller as a service for reuse later in other controllers but I am not clear whether it is a good practice, here's a good article analyzing this issue [Symfony2: Make my Controllers Services?](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/question-answer-day/controllers-services)

  - on the one hand [How to Define Controllers as Services](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/cookbook/controller/service.html)
  - and on the other a comment for Fabien Potencier [Mention best practice "controller as a service" in chapter Controller # 457](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/457) and [The 'New' symfony Best Practices](http://blog.fazy.net/symfony-2-best-practices/#controllersasaservice)
- Create an abstract BaseController. Of which it is spoken here, but the idea is not developed.[Symfony2 and be DRY approach in controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9700402/5763965)

Any idea how to solve this scenario?

thanks a lot

Comment: Do the calculations in a service (just create a "CalculationService", preferably with a better name..) and then use this service in the controllers. Defining controllers as a service is more a convention, it allows you to inject whatever you need instead of fetching them from the container.

Comment: i'd use the service option. Another way would be to forward the data to another controller but the service solution would be far better idea... less overhead

Comment: What @JimL suggested, I use this approach a lot, works great.

Comment: I understand then to say **Controllers as Services** is simply a convention, and that really does not have to be considered a controller, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Services seem to be much corresponding with the described usage.

Recently, I worked on an accounting solution. I used a lot of complex algorithms and I soon had very long methods, even trying to optimise code.

Services are easily callable, and their usage can make controllers so much sexier, lighter, and make big methods readable and more cuttable by using separated services corresponding to specific actions.

And they can be used in other components, as long as DependencyInjection is present, it's a sufficient raison to move your logic if you may need apply it in another context that a controller.

It's simple to declare it :

```
services:
    acmeapp.calculation:
        class: Acme\AppBundle\Services\CalculationService
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", "@acmeapp.anotherservice"]
```

And the service

```
class CalculationService {

    protected $em;
    protected $another;

    public function __constructor(EntityManager $entityManager, AnotherService $anotherService)
    {
        $this->em = $entityManager;
        $this->another = $anotherService;
    }

    //...
}
```

The Controller-Service approach is primarily a service, with all its advantages.
A method of your service can render a view and have a route associated using the `_controller` attribute, like this :

```
display_data_a:
    path:     /data/A
    methods: GET
    defaults: { _controller: acmeapp.calculation:dealWithData }
```

Without extending your service from the  `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller`, but, of course, you can use it.

Also, an abstract `BaseController` can be a very clean alternative, if you have many duplicated code with a few different characters between your controllers.
It's what I'm doing before use services, if the methods are corresponding with my definition of a controller, which is corresponding to what @fabpot says in your link.

> The DIC mostly helps manage "global" objects. Controllers are not global objects. Moreover, a controller should be as thin as possible. It's mainly the glue between your Model and the View/Templates. So, if you need to be able to customize then, it probably means that you need to refactor them and extract the business logic from them.

More about BaseController in OOP,

The way is simple, if you have a line of code that repeats itself two or three times in a method, you use a variable.
Same for a block of code, you will use a method.
For controllers it's the same, if you have two or more objects of the same type (here a controller), you should use an AbstractController (or BaseController), move your duplicated methods in it (only once, of course), and remove them from the child controllers.

BaseController :

```
class BaseController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Shortcut for get doctrine entity manager.
     */
    public function getEntityManager()
    {
        return $this->getDoctrine->getEntityManager();
    }

    /**
     * Shortcut for locate a resource in the application.
     */
    public function locateResource($path)
    {
        return $this->get('kernel')->locateResource($path);
    }

    // ...
}
```

And use it as part of your child controllers

```
class ChildController extends BaseController
{
    public function helloAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $file = $this->locateResource('@AcmeAppBundle/Resources/config/hello.yml');
        // ...
    }

}
```

Hope this helps you to avoid a lot of a duplicated code.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I see everything more clearly

Comment: I just see the part about AbstractController in your question, you just have to create a class called BaseController, abstract or not, extend it from the Symfony Controller (your controllers are currently extending from it) , add your generic methods inside, and then extend all your controllers from this AbstractController. That's it, a simple inheritance but very helpful.

Comment: Although you explain quite well would you be so kind as to put a code sample? Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, Symfony2 is a very good platform to expand this kind of stuff.
I've added an example.