# Best place to implement a method that return response in Symfony2/MVC

Tags: symfony, oop, model-view-controller

I got a method able to create a CSV file thanks to StreamedResponse object of Symfony2 framework. I use the method several times so I put a callback parameter to personalise the behavior (I forget the buzz word for this practice in Object-Oriented Programming).

Where is the best place to put this method in a MVC project?

- Repository? (Model/DAO/Manager)
- Entity? (POPO)
- Controller
- Service
- Through a interface (This object able to create CSV file)
- Other

Comment: If you need some examples, say me.

Comment: You got it :) See my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your logic returns a response, the most adapted context is a controller.

Also, if your logic is called from multiple contexts or by multiple classes of the same context (e.g. controllers), to avoid duplicated code, you have two possibilities (at least) :

1 - Use an AbstractController and make your controllers extends the abstract.

2- Use a service (i.e. CsvManager).

If you want some example implementations, see [Symfony2 reusable functions in controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34752765/4363634) and the [Controller as a service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html) chapter of the Symfony documentation.

An example of service implementation:

```
// src/AppBundle/Services/CsvManager.php

class CsvManager
{
    public function generate(/** params */)
    {
        // Return your streamed response    
    }
}
```

The service declaration :

```
// app/config/services.yml
services:
    # ...
    app.csv_manager:
        class: AppBundle\Services\CsvManager
```

Now, you can use the service from all your controllers and other contexts that implements the services container. example:

```
// src/AppBundle/Controller/TestController.php;

class TestController extends \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller
{
    public function printCsvAction()
    {
        $csvManager = $this->get('app.csv_manager');

        return $csvManager->generate(/** params */);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1.  From personal experience I'd go with #2 - you can create an export service of some sorts that returns your streamed response and re-use very easily by passing whatever data you need to it.  Then you'd just have your controller return the response from the service

Comment: Definitely option #2! As @JasonRoman have mention, your code will be clean and reusable. The problem with the #1st method is that, your abstract controller will have logic which is not necessary for other controllers or won't be usable in case of demand for few abstract controllers.

Comment: I agree with you. He can also use the service as the `_controller` of a route and render the response from it directly

Comment: Too much effort don't worry I use `goodby/csv` :p. So basically to create a service, I need to create a Bundle or just a Controller that implement the CSV method, declare the service and then use it. Got it, thank you.